# Mailto link spam protection

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

I developed a wordpress themes ages ago and had this script going in a `script.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spampro').each(function() {
    var email = $(this).find('.n').text() + "@" + $(this).find('.e1').text() + "." + $(this).find('.e2').text();
    $(this).html("<a href=\"mailto:" + email + "\">" + email + "</a>");
  });
});
});
});
```

Now years after when I wanted to use it again I cant recall how I used to get my mailto/email addresses protected. I have a small memory of when I wrote: `myemail@adress.com` it was encoded in the page source.

I searched for the `.spampro` without any success. Perhaps will any of you be familiar of how I used it since i'm not a code wizard.

Comment: This won't help you much with today's crawlers running the JS on your site.

Answer (score 0):

That script appears to be looking for the following HTML structure, and replacing it with a link tag:

```js
$('.spampro').each(function() {
  var email = $(this).find('.n').text() +
    "@" + $(this).find('.e1').text() +
    "." + $(this).find('.e2').text();
  $(this).html("<a href=\"mailto:" + email + "\">" + email + "</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spampro">
  <span class="n">name</span>
  <span class="e1">example</span>
  <span class="e2">com</span>
</div>
```

I very much doubt this technique would provide any protection at all from email harvesters these days -- all they'd need to do is allow your page to finish running the above script before scraping.

Comment: You guys are probably right but thank you so much for your time and for helping me out. really appreciated. have a great day everyone.